# Shop relaunch failed - no orders anymore

Tags: checkout, orders, sales

Recently we launched a redesigned shop: www.fumalo.com . Now it passed 1 1/2 months. Since then only one single order has been transacted. The page views broke in with about 50% but is now raising again. The page with highest jump-off is the homepage...strange right?

Before it was also Magento, but just a cheap theme and v1.5 instead of now v1.9.

We checked the functionality of checkout and we took care of url rewrites. The Design is not at its final stage and also the responsive could be better, but hey...its thousand times better then the old theme, even if its not perfect.

So maybe you guys have an answer...maybe its obvious, but I don't see it.

Thanks a lot for feedback

Comment: Although this does seem like an online marketing, instead Magento programing question, I will try to help.
 At the moment, when I entered the address, it looked more like Wordpress publicist or portfolio site, while the 1st slider was animating itself and not an e-commerce site. 
Why not change the slider to start with assorted collection of products / prices ? Or at least a specific, hot-seller product and it's price, instead of a large logo animating itself for a whole second...

Comment: hey SGOTW! this is a great feedback. sounds very logic what you are saying. i made these changes right away added a slide promoting products directly. 

i think we will increase the work on the slider and add more stuff to it, the next weeks.

still it doesnt explain why returning visitors, that knew the store in its old shape dont buy anymore...still odd

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I see a huge issue right off the bat that is likely leading to little or no sales: When you try to add a product to your cart, it goes to a white page. Nothing on it...it looks like you just went to the end of the website. :-)

And, in addition to that, if you go back to your website, it didn't add it to the cart. So, even if a customer gives the benefit of the doubt and navigates back to the homepage after being brought to a blank page, they don't have anything in their cart. It's a vicious cycle, which leads to 0 orders.

I think if you resolve this, orders will start coming through again.

-Kaylie

Comment: hey Kaylie! thanks for the reply! its great, you took the time to check the shop. the issue you are mentioning was due to an extension I activated yesterday - so it is a pretty new bug. the whole month the cart function was working...

Comment: Glad I could at least help pinpoint that! Unfortunately, without more background on how your traffic has changed or having an account to test checkout with, it's hard to say why purchasing has dropped off completely. - Kaylie